# Why my AngularJS view is not getting updated after AJAX call with Parse.com JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, parse-platform

Here's my View

```
<div ng-repeat="blog in blogs">
<h3>{{blog.title}}</h3>
<h4>{{blog.post}}</h4>
</div>
```

My Controller Code:

```
   demoApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'blogService', function ($scope,   
    blogService)
    {
        $scope.blogs = blogService.getBlogs();
    }]);
```

My code in the service. This includes asynchronous call to Parse.com javascript sdk.

```
this.getBlogs = function () 
{        
   var BlogPost = Parse.Object.extend("BlogPost");
   var blogPost = new BlogPost();
   var blogs  = [];
    var query = new Parse.Query(BlogPost);
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            console.log(results[0].get("title"));
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                blogs.push(
                    {
                        title : results[i].get("title"),
                        post : results[i].get("post")
                    });
            }
            console.log(blogs);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
    return blogs;
}; });
```

The console log `console.log(blogs);` is showing returned data perfectly. Just the view is not getting updated after this value is fetched.

Comment: did u updated ng-app as demoApp to your html

<html ng-app="demoApp">

and ng- controller to the parent div of your code

Comment: Have a look at Promises in Parse Doc vs Callbacks to make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the callbacks executes "outside of Angular's world", which means the $digest loop will not be triggered and changes will not be reflected in the DOM.

You need to use [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

Inject `$rootScope` in your service and for example:

```
success: function(results) {
  $rootScope.$apply(function () { 
    console.log(results[0].get("title"));
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
        blogs.push(
            {
                title : results[i].get("title"),
                post : results[i].get("post")
            });
    }
    console.log(blogs);
  });
},
```

Comment: Oh this helped! I was stuck at this for 2 hours! Thanks a lot :-) :-) :-) It is working perfectly now :-)

Comment: There may be some concerns using `$rootScope` inside a service. Running `$rootScope.$apply` applies to all scopes (technically runs all "digest loops"), so can consume a lot of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your "success" callback executes asynchronously and angular doesn't know when it happens. To inform angular about the success callback you could wrap it in $scope.$apply

```
success: function(results) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        console.log(results[0].get("title"));
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            blogs.push(
                {
                    title : results[i].get("title"),
                    post : results[i].get("post")
                });
        }
        console.log(blogs);
    });
}
```

Comment: This piece of code is inside the Service,  not Controller, so there is no `$scope` there.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Service return Promise!

```
.factory('factoryReturningPromise', function (){
   ...
  return query.find()

  .then(function(results){
     ...
    // make sure the return value is a resolved promise
    return Parse.Promise.as(blog);
  },

  function(error){

    // we are here because of query error - return rejected promise
    return Parse.Promise.error(error);
  });
})
```

Then you only need to wrap it into local `$scope.$apply` inside your controller:

```
.controller('myController', function ($scope, factoryReturningPromise) {
   $scope.$apply(function(){

      blogService.getBlogs()

      .then(function(blogs){

        $scope.blogs = blogs;
      }, function (error) {

        ... and deal with errors ... show bad news to user etc
      });
   });
})
```

That way only local digest loops with all the watches will be checked.